# To get unchecked checkboxes in jsf Datatable Multiple Select

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

How to uncheck all checkbox of the records when JSF datatable is populated in the beginning ?

Comment: How do you mean? They are not checked by default.

Comment: problem i am facing is i am disabling some rows by using disable selection but still when i click and hit submit the disabled rows get selected. How to avoid this?

Comment: Maybe by using a more current version than PrimeFaces 3.0